# Connect to vpn network on startup

Tags: vpn, systemd-startup

I have installed openvpn on my raspberry pi:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

I can connect to my VPN server with command:

```
 sudo openvpn confyg.ovpn
```

Everything runs fine, but what is the best way to start `openvpn` client when system starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use `cron`

Easiest way to setup something like this is to use `crontab`. Since the command `openvpn` is run with `sudo` when manually started, we will edit crontab with `sudo`. This will start the cron job as root. Use the command below:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This will open a new or existing file using the default text editor. If no editor was selected before, select `nano` as the editor.

At the end of the open file add the following line:

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/openvpn /full/path/to/confyg.ovpn 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/vpn_connect.log
```

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes. Then<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the `nano` editor.

Reboot and test if it is working by checking the external IP.

If it does not work, look at the content of the file `/var/log/vpn_connect.log`. It will have the error messages if any.

Hope this helps

Comment: Consider augmenting your answer to capture any error messages (via `stderr`) to a file for a *post-mortem*?

Comment: @Seamus Thanks! Done. Let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: I'm curious about the pipe to `tee`... the output of the `openvpn` command isn't going anywhere except to the .log file; why wouldn't a redirect (`>>`) work?

Comment: @Seamus `>>` works too. I used `sudo openvpn ... | sudo tee ...` for testing, as `>>` does not work when the normal user does not have write permission to the `/var/log/ folder. However, it is not necessary (but is sufficient) in cron.

Answer (score 1):

## Use Systemd

In order to configure OpenVPN to autostart using systemd, complete the following steps:

Run the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/openvpn
```

and uncomment, or remove, the “#” in front of

```
AUTOSTART="all"
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the text editor.

Copy the .ovpn file with the desired server location to the ‘/etc/openvpn’ folder:

```
sudo cp /location/whereYouDownloadedConfigfilesTo/confyg.ovpn /etc/openvpn/
```

Edit the .ovpn file you copied in the previous step and change the line `auth-user-pass` to `auth-user-pass pass`:

```
sudo nano /etc/openvpn/confyg.ovpn
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the text editor.

In the `/etc/openvpn` folder, create a text file called pass:

```
sudo nano /etc/openvpn/pass
```

and enter your VPN **Account ID** on the first line and VPN **password** on the second line, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the text editor.

Change the permissions on the pass file to protect the credentials:

```
sudo chmod 400 /etc/openvpn/pass
```

Rename the `confyg.ovpn` file to `client.conf`:

```
sudo mv /etc/openvpn/confyg.ovpn /etc/openvpn/client.conf
```

Enable the `openvpn@` service with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable openvpn@client.service
```

Reload the daemons:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start the OpenVPN service:

```
sudo service openvpn@client start
```

Reboot and test if it is working by checking the external IP.

Adapted from: https://www.ivpn.net/knowledgebase/linux/linux-autostart-openvpn-in-systemd-ubuntu/

Hope this helps